# Standard name for ideals generated by a subset of indeterminates?

Tags: terminology, ideals, monomial-ideals

I have been working on a problem in the polynomial ring $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$, where I've been dealing with ideals generated by subsets of the indeterminates, i.e.,
ideals of the form $$\langle x_i\mid i\in A\rangle,$$ for subsets $A\subseteq \{1,\ldots,n\}$.

Is there a standard name for such ideals?

Comment: Perhaps degree one monomial ideals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I had guessed that "coordinate ideal" would be a natural name, but that term didn't come up in a first google search. However, I have just [found a paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0905.4511.pdf) that does indeed used this term, and so that settles it for me.